# CherryPy running tut01 file on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy

Bit of info: Python 3.2.3, 
Cherrypy version 3.2.2. Windows 7 64-bit.

Installed Cherrypy, set up PATH with the right Python directory, etc. However, whenever I run the tutorial file (tut01, Hello world) or any other python file with the same code, I get the following output:

> F:\Code>python helloworld.py [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Listening
>   for SIGTERM. [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Bus STARTING CherryPy
>   Checker: The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.
>
> [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Started monitor thread
>   '_TimeoutMonitor'. [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Started monitor
>   thread 'Autoreloader'. [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Error in 'start'
>   listener > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 197,
>   in publish
>       output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cpserver.py", line 150, in
>   start
>
> ```
> self.httpserver, self.bind_addr = self.httpserver_from_self()   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpserver.py", line 140,
> ```
>
> in https erver_from_self
>       from cherrypy import _cpwsgi_server   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cpwsgi_server.py", line 7, in
>   
>       from cherrypy import wsgiserver   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver__init__.py", line
>   14,  in 
>       exec('from .wsgiserver3 import *')   File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named wsgiserver3
>
> [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start
>   listener: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 235,
>   in start
>       self.publish('start')   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 215,
>   in publish
>       raise exc cherrypy.process.wspbus.ChannelFailures: ImportError('No module named wsgiserver 3',)
>
> [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Bus STOPPING [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22]
>   ENGINE HTTP Server None already shut down [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22]
>   ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'. [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE
>   Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'. [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Bus
>   STOPPED [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Bus EXITING
>   [29/Nov/2012:22:37:22] ENGINE Bus EXITED

And pointing browser to localhost:8080 does nothing, when it should show Hello World.

Pretty sure I did everything correctly according to the installation guide on the Cherrypy website. Not entirely sure how to fix it, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the import errors. Has anyone else had success with installing cherrypy on windows for python3?

Found a solution: https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1110/cherrypy-322win32exe-installer-didnt

The original installer was missing the wsgiserver3 module, which was needed for it to work on Python 3.x. The above installer should fix the issue.

Comment: So it was missing module in cherrypy, you should put that as the answer to this question. Just for the record.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this, there is a simple solution:

1. clone the repository to your local machine.
2. navigate to the root folder and execute the following command: `python setup.py install`

It is mentioned in the README.txt [here in the official source repo](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src).

Answer (score 1):

Just to notice that this is a answered question, quoting rashdanml:

> Found a solution: https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1110/cherrypy-322win32exe-installer-didnt?
>
> The original installer was missing the wsgiserver3 module, which was needed for it to work on Python 3.x. The above installer should fix the issue.